# How closely does Pokemon Ranger/Mystery Dungeon follow main game format?

Tags: pokemon-series, pokemon-mystery-dungeon, pokemon-ranger

I have finished the main Pokémon series but the before mentioned games seem really different. How do they match the main game and do I need to get the first in the series to progress?

Comment: The *Pokémon Mystery Dungeon* series uses a limited subset of mainline Pokémon combat mechanics (type matchups, etc.) but are ultimately dungeon crawlers that play much closer to roguelikes (with procedurally-generated dungeons, for starters) than anything else. The *PMD* series is part of Spike Chunsoft's *Mystery Dungeon* franchise, which itself is designed after the original *Rogue*. Not familiar with the Pokémon Ranger series, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're nothing like the main Pokemon games. In the Mystery Dungeon games, you are exploring dungeons and levelling pokemon and going on quests. Pokemon Ranger is more about collecting Pokemon (but not using them in teams or for fighting or anything) and solving puzzles and completing tasks.

Neither of those series really follow each other in any way - every Mystery Dungeon or Pokemon Ranger game can be played as a standalone title, and you won't be missing out on any story or anything. Each game will explain any controls/story/etc elements that you might need to know.

Comment: Are any of them compatible with tge main games eg trade/transfer pokemon or items?

Comment: No, they're not connected like that.

Comment: Well there was that manaphy egg but besides that, no.

Comment: @Pezantish Some pokemon can be transferred over. See [my answer here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/149843/58396)

Comment: Just get explorers of sky and some tissues